# advcheckbox in moodle form is storing only 0 in database

Tags: plugins, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-theme

I am new Moodle and working on form data saving. I have created a group of checkbox which will take some input from the users and store it to the database, but unfortunately it is storing only 0/1 in the database. I have no clue where I made the mistake.
This my php file where I added the form field-

```
class custom_signup_form extends moodleform {

    //Add elements to form
    public function definition() {
        global $CFG;
        global $DB;
        $mform = $this->_form; // Don't forget the underscore! 

        //$mform->addElement('text', 'email', get_string('email')); // Add elements to your form.
        //$mform->setType('email', PARAM_NOTAGS);                   // Set type of element.
        //$mform->setDefault('email', 'Please enter email');        // Default value.

        if($this->content !== Null){
            return $this->content;
        }

        
        $courses = $DB->get_records('course');
        $categories = $DB->get_records('course_categories');


        $interestedcourse=array();
        foreach($courses as $course){
            $coursestring = $course->fullname;
            $interestedcourse[] =  $mform->createElement('advcheckbox', 'interestedcourse[]','', $coursestring, array('group' => 1), array('',$coursestring));
        }
        $mform->addGroup($interestedcourse, 'interestedcoursegroup', get_string('interestedcourse', 'assignsubmission_metadata'),array('<br>'), false);

        $interestedcategory=array();
        foreach($categories as $category){
            $categorystring = $category->name;
            $interestedcategory[] =  $mform->createElement('advcheckbox', 'interestedcategory[]','', $categorystring, array('group' => 1), array('',$categorystring));
        }
        $mform->addGroup($interestedcategory, 'interestedcategorygroup', get_string('interestedcategory', 'assignsubmission_metadata'),array('<br>'), false);

        $this->add_action_buttons();
```

This is the php file for saving form data-

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../config.php');
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/local/custom_signup/classes/form/edit.php');

global $DB;


$PAGE->set_url(new moodle_url('/local/custom_signup/signupform.php'));
$PAGE->set_title(get_string('custom_signup', 'local_custom_signup'));

#custom form for signup

$mform = new custom_signup_form();

if ($mform->is_cancelled()) {
    // Go back to manage.php page
    redirect($CFG->wwwroot . '/local/custom_signup/manage.php', get_string('cancelled_form', 'local_message'));

}
else if ($fromform = $mform->get_data()) {

    var_dump($fromform);
    die;

}


echo $OUTPUT->header();

$mform->display();
echo $OUTPUT->render_from_template('local_custom_signup/signupform', $templatecontext);

echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

object returned from the form submission-

```
object(stdClass)#288 (3) { ["interestedcourse"]=> array(1) { [""]=> string(0) "" } ["interestedcategory"]=> array(1) { [""]=> string(0) "" } ["submitbutton"]=> string(12) "Save changes" }
```

Comment: I'm not able to give you a full answer to this, but I've usually had more success by using something like: $mform->createElement('advcheckbox', "interestedcategory[$catid]", ...); That way you get an array in the form data with $catid mapped onto 0 or 1. If that doesn't help, I'd suggest setting up xdebug and stepping through the code to see what is happening.

Comment: @davosmith thanks for the response. I have checked with you solution but same result. I have checked inspect element there I saw it creates <input> with the desire value, but it can't seems to pass that value to the database. If you can help me with the some resource or anything can help me find the issue would be great.